# Performing switching time test with NMOS (5LN01SP)

Tags: transistors, mosfet, inverter, nmos, fet

I am about to feed my switching time test circuit with input signal from signal generator. In a 5LN01SP's [specification](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/learn_tutorials/4/2/3/5ln01sp.PDF) input test signal is marked as:

PW = 10us
D.C. <= 1%

(see the picture)
[image]

It is clear pulse high level state is 10us (4V). **I am not sure whether D.C. there stands for duty cycle or DC** (direct current)

and if it's latter:

I would like to confirm it's 20 us long pulse with duty cycle of 50% (thus 10us high level state). What about D.C. ?

if it's the first:

I would like to confirm it's 1000us long pulse with duty cycle of 1% (thus again 10us high level).

Comment: It's duty cycle.

Comment: That would be my guess. Thank you @Andyaka

Comment: The IEEE says to use "duty factor" instead of "duty cycle". This is an example of one confusion that could be avoided.

Comment: Absolutely. Agreed.